# Need to reload page twice, when calling woocommerce_product_query

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I've got these 3 functions in my functions.php (sorry for the newbie code).

There's a submit button, and a dropdown. User selects a country in the list of options and press submit. The custom_product_query_tax_query is then run, and sorts the products by the slug Denmark or Europa. It's working, however, I need to press the submit button twice, or atleast reload the page manually for the changes to be visible.

Do I need to call the woocommerce_product_query before other content, or am I simply doing it all wrong?

```
//Before shop loop we inject the dropdown form with submit button.
//We also preselect the last option choosen, based on the country in session.
function report_button()
{
    // display button only on posts
    if ( !is_single() )
    {
    $retrive_data = WC()->session->get( 'Country' );
        $denmark = '';
        $europe = '';
        if($retrive_data === 'Denmark')
        {
            $denmark = 'selected';
        }
        else
        {
            $europe = 'selected';
        }
    $content .= '<form action="" method="POST">
                    <select name="select_name[]" id="">
                        <option value="Europe" '. $europe .'>Vis alle produkter</option>
                        <option value="Denmark" '. $denmark .'>Vis kun lovlige i Danmark</option>
                    </select>
                <input type="submit">
                </form>';
    echo $content;
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'report_button', 10 );

//On submit, we set the selected country in a session variable.
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'wpse149613_form_process' );
function wpse149613_form_process()
{
    if(isset($_POST['select_name'])){ // select_name will be replaced with your input filed name
        $getInput = $_POST['select_name']; // select_name will be replaced with your input filed name
        foreach ($getInput as $option => $value) {
            $selectedOption = $value;
            WC()->session->set( 'Country' , $selectedOption );
        }
    }
}

//Custom woocommerce product query, show only products with Slug, Denmark.
function custom_product_query_tax_query( $q )
{
    if( is_admin() ) return $q;

    $retrive_data = WC()->session->get( 'Country' );

    if ( $retrive_data == 'Denmark' )
    {        
        $tax_query = (array) $q->get( 'tax_query' );

        $tax_query[] = array(
               'taxonomy' => 'product_tag',
               'field' => 'slug',
               'terms' => array( 'Denmark' ),
               'operator' => 'IN'
        );
        $q->set( 'tax_query', $tax_query );
    }
    else
    {
        return $q;
    }
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'custom_product_query_tax_query', 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I seem to have found the answer elsewhere. The template_redirect function hook, needs somewhere to redirect to. I added this to the buttom of the code, and it works!

```
    $current_url = home_url( add_query_arg( array(), $wp->request ) );
    wp_redirect($current_url);
    exit;
```